# How to display child custom term under parent

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to display in sidebar a widget with custom taxonomy list.
All works fine but when I add a subcategory, this is displayed as a category and not in right order (under your parent)

Example, in my backend:

CARS 
-FERRARI
-LAMBORGHINI
BIKE
MOTO

in frontend:

FERRARI
CARS
BIKE
MOTO
LAMBORGHINI

```
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'categorie_area_riservata',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );

        echo '<ul class="widget_categories">';

        // loop through all terms
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {

            // Get the term link
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

            if( $term->count > 0 )  
            // display link to term archive
            echo '<li class="cat-item"><a href="' . esc_url( 
                         $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name .'</a></li>';

            elseif( $term->count !== 0 )
            // display name
            echo '' . $term->name .'';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: you need to convert array in parent child manner. then apply foreach and do ul li stuff

Comment: Your input data is not well defined in your question.  There is no benefit to concatenating zero-width strings to your echoed variables.  Because I can't fathom `->count` producing a negative number, I have to assume that your `elseif` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

I solve in simple way.

```
      echo '<ul class="categories">';

    wp_list_categories(
        array(

            'taxonomy' => 'categorie_area_riservata',
            'title_li' => '',
            'depth' => 2,
        )
    );


   echo '</ul>';
```

and css class

```
ul.categories a {color:#444444;}
ul.categories a:hover {color:#1c57a1;}

/*child term*/

ul.children  {padding-left:50px !important;}

ul.children li {
 padding-bottom: 0 !important;
 padding-top: 0px;
 margin-top: 3px !important;
 }
```